# select using case or if and also case or if at where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a complex situation. I want to use a case (or if) at Select clause, then also case (or if) at where clause, to do something like the below:

```
select SP.SUBSCR, SP.PARAM2, cdit.ECAM,
    (CASE WHEN SP.PARAM2 LIKE 'PP%' THEN SP2.PARAM
        ELSE 'NOT FOUND' 
    END)
from tableA sp, tableA sp2, tableOther cdit
where SP2.SUBSCR = SP.SUBSCR 
  and SP.SER = 'Avalue'
  and SP.PARAM = 'Bvalue' 
  and SP2.SERV in
    (CASE WHEN SP.PARAM2 LIKE 'PP%' THEN 'PP1'
      ELSE NULL
    END)
  and SP2.PARAM in 
    (CASE WHEN SP.PARAM2 LIKE 'PP%' THEN 'PP2'
      ELSE NULL
    END)
  and CDIT.PAR = SP.PARAM2
  and SP.SUBSCR in ('Anum', 'Bnum');
```

What I need to do is to: Use `SP2.PARAM` at Select, only when `SP.PARAM2` is `like 'PP%'` and also use (set values) for `SP2.SERV` and `SP2.PARAM` only when SP.PARAM2 is again `like 'PP%'`, else I do not want to set any values for `SP2.SERV` and `SP2.PARAM`, or have them to be `null`.

Unfortunately, it appears that above SQL works for cases that the `SP.PARAM2` is `like 'PP%'`, it never works for cases that the `SP.PARAM2` is `NOT like 'PP%'`, thus never displays `'NOT FOUND'` at the output.
My guess is that it always tries to set values for `SP2.SERV` and `SP2.PARAM` at the where clause `CASE`, which is strange, since the `SP.PARAM2` is certainly not always like `'PP%'`. 
Therefore I might not be using the `CASE` correctly, mainly at where clause.

Hope that my explanation is clear.

Maybe I could use IF instead of CASE, but I have no idea how, I am open to suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: You know that when SP2.PARAM in NULL no rows at all will be returned?

Answer (score 0):

> Select, only when SP.PARAM2 is like 'PP%' and also use (set values) for SP2.SERV and SP2.PARAM only when SP.PARAM2 is again like 'PP%', else I do not want to set any values for SP2.SERV and SP2.PARAM, or have them to be null.
>
> ELSE NULL

When the **ELSE** part is executed, you are comparing the column value with **NULL**. Something like, `SP2.SERV in NULL` which will never return anything.

If you don't want to include anything other than `PP1` then don't have an ELSE condition in the CASE expression while filtering the rows in the query predicate. `ELSE NULL`

You WHERE clause could be modified as:

```
AND SP2.SERV IN
(
  CASE
  WHEN SP.PARAM2 LIKE 'PP%' THEN
    'PP1'
  END) 
AND SP2.PARAM IN
(
  CASE
  WHEN SP.PARAM2 LIKE 'PP%' THEN
    'PP2'
  END)
```

If you want to include the rows which do not meet the PP1 condition, then for **NOT LIKE** condition, make it **always TRUE**. Also, the `IN` operator is useless here, simply use `=`:

```
AND SP2.SERV =
(
  CASE
  WHEN SP.PARAM2 LIKE 'PP%' THEN
    'PP1'
  ELSE SP2.SERV
  END) 
AND SP2.PARAM =
(
  CASE
  WHEN SP.PARAM2 LIKE 'PP%' THEN
    'PP2'
  ELSE SP.PARAM2
  END)
```

Make the necessary changes in the **SELECT** too if required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with Oracle but surely Oracle has the notion of `join`s and specifically `left join`s, no? With a `left join`, you add fields from the joined table when a condition is met. If the condition is not met, the row isn't dismissed entirely as it would be with `join` or with the way you are joining now, simply adding more tables to the `from` clause.

So I would think you wanna do something like this:

```
select SP.SUBSCR, SP.PARAM2, cdit.ECAM, NVL(SP2.PARAM, 'NOT FOUND')
from tableA sp
join tableOther cdit on cdit.PAR = sp.PARAM2
left join tableA sp2 on sp2.SUBSCR = sp.SUBSCR
                    and sp2.SERV = 'PP1'
                    and sp2.PARAM = 'PP2'
                    and sp.PARAM2 LIKE 'PP%'

where SP.SER = 'Avalue'
  and SP.PARAM = 'Bvalue' 
  and SP.SUBSCR in ('Anum', 'Bnum');
```

So now, the fields in `sp2` are only added if all the conditions listed after `on` are met.